# Loop through multiple netcdf files

Tags: grads

I would like to loop through multiple netcdf files in GrADS. The files run from May 1, 2018 to June 30, 2018 named as:

2018050100.nc...2018063000.nc

The function is to regrid the netcdf files to 0.17 degrees. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use grads for that at all.

You can just go for CDO (climate data operators)

The command is simple.

1) Create a grid file and save it in text format with name "grd"

gridtype = lonlat
xsize    =
ysize    =
xfirst   =
xinc     =
yfirst   =
yinc     =

2)Go to your shell and type the following command

```
 FILES=*.nc
 for i in $FILES
 cdo remapbil,grd $i $j  
 done
```

3)Now you have a folder full of your regridded files